# Mongo $in / $all not working like expected

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Consider this NodeJS route with the provided query:

```
app.post("/api/test", async function(req, res) {

    const findTags = ["banana", "produce", "yellow", "organic", "fruit"];

    Product.find({
      tags: {
        $size: findTags.length,
        $in: findTags
      }
    })
      .sort({ date: "descending" })
      .limit(20)
      .exec(function(err, docs) {
        console.log("Query found these products: ");
        console.log(docs);
      });
});
```

Inside of my MongoDB, I have the following two entries:

```
{
    name: "Banana",
    "tags": [
        "banana",
        " produce",
        " yellow",
        " organic",
        " fruit"
    ]
},
{
    name: "Blueberry",
    "tags": [
        "organic",
        " produce",
        " blue",
        " blueberries",
        " fruit"
    ]
}
```

I expected the query to return only `Banana` back

**Actual Result:** Both `Banana`, and `Blueberry` were returned back.

So I tried replacing `$in` with `$all`, and all I get back is an empty array. Meaning it hasn't found anything! How is this possible?

**What I'm trying to do:** I want to find all `Products` that have *at least* all of the `findTags`. It's okay if the product has 100 more tags as long as it has all of the tags I'm looking for.

How would I change my query to make that happen?

Comment: `$all`  doesn't work because you have spaces in the tags.

Comment: DING DING DING. I'm thinking that's it!!

Comment: @Phillip In DB entries there is space before each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$all` does not work for you, because `tags` in the documents does not match `tags` from the query.
Some `tags` contains trailing space (e.g. `produce`) in the documents

Comment: Hahaha there's spaces in my tags... Omg

Answer (score -3):

You have to write query like this. And you also have to remove spaces from your db. or make query of tags with space.

```
var tagsArr = ["banana", "produce", "yellow", "organic", "fruit"];
var query = {tags: {$all: tagsArr } };

Product.find(query).sort({ date: "descending" })
  .limit(20)
  .exec(function(err, docs) {
    console.log("Query found these products: ");
    console.log(docs);
  });
```

Comment: You just saved the query into a variable, and added "name" which is not needed. This does not fix the problem

Comment: You need to delete the spaces from tags in db collection. then hit the query.